# how to execute php in html file like in home page

Tags: php, html

Problem is: **I have a website let www.mydomain.com
and it loads index.html, in this file i write some php code but it is not executing**
Some days ago i found the solution for executing **php in .html** file that simply just make a line in .htaccess: (works perfectly in **.html** files)

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

In my case above code not working, here problem is that in address bar my link index.html start as mydomain.com so as it is not representing file extension may be thats why above htaccess code not working.
Help me please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually name your home file "index.php". There just can't be an index.html at the same time (unless editing some configuration stuff).

Comment: if i can't change it  to .php ? is there anyway to execute in index.html file

Comment: not for that reason, and web host has php but the problem is that this website is not mine, (a client site) so my job is to create a contact form (i created that contact form using php) in index.html so thats why i am worried about that if i change index.html to index.php it may cause some problems

Comment: I can only say that this makes no sense to me. Basically, the user won't notice any difference if you just copy the original content from index.html into index.php.

Comment: @BlackCetha Unless there are existing links to index.html that would then need to be changed.

Comment: @PatrickQ - you could simply redirect from the index.html to the index.php

Comment: @PatrickQ Wich is kind of a mistake in the links then, because normally you would just link to "/". Otherwise, you would have "doma.in/index.html" in the adress bar.

Comment: @AnuragBabaresco - So it needs a copy file of index.html to index.php!

Comment: @BlackCetha I don't disagree. But given the lack of foresight/understanding that seems to be present here, it is certainly possible.

Comment: @BlackCetha rights i should to change it to index.php as because we didn't use extensions in linking

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an iFrame would work, which you place in index.html. You can place your PHP code in another page e.g. `form.php` and load that page in the iFrame. You'd have to do a lot of testing to make sure the functionality is given, as iFrames can cause all sorts of issues, especially, but not limited to, IE.